# Find files in all child folders, then rename all to increment filenumber

Tags: powershell

It seems like an easy task though I can't get it to work. I got many `jpg` files, all named `1.jpg`, stored in about 700 child folders. Where is my error?

My code:

```
$int = 1
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*'1'*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '1', $int++ }
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: Is this a typo? `- replace` should be `-replace` without a space for starters. Are you getting an error? Also I would think that this would error out as is since you do not have a line continuation after `-NewName` What about this is not working. `$_` is generally used inside a statement like `ForEach` or `Select`. Your quotes dont look right either but that might be a copy issue `‘` vs. `'`

Comment: While it would work I would recommend using `-Path` of `Get-ChildItem` to ensure you are working with the correct direcory. Does your filter even work? `"*’1’*"` you have nested quotes so i'm not sure that would filter correctly. I see you are taking some of my comments to heart

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it all but everything seems to be correct. The  line continuation after `-NewName` and the `‘` vs. `'` were both a copy issue. When trying to pass `1` as integer without quotes I get this error :  `Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:1 char:40
+ Get-ChildItem -Filter "*1*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '1 ...`, and when trying as in my original question I get no error but the files name stays the same. About `-Path` before `Get-ChildItem`, doesn't it suppose to work with `Dir` if I navigated to the source directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$int = 2
Get-ChildItem -Filter 1.jpg -Recurse | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '1', $int++}
```

Concerning `$int = 2`. You need to start one number higher since the first file you would fine would try to rename 1.jpg to 1.jpg. `$int++` would increase the number *after* is was used in the substitution for `-replace`.

Have to find the documentation to back this up but part of your issue might have been using a scriptblock `{}` when a subexpression `()` would have worked just fine.

Also since you know the file name I would think the filter should just be `"1.jpg"` that way you wont get other files you don't want.

**About `-Path` with `Get-ChildItem`**

You do not *need* to specify it at all as it will use the current location as it's path. It is good practice to use path so that way you wouldn't accidentally run code against a path you did not mean to. Case and point is you search for the number 1 could easily match files that were not 1.jpg. Renaming all of those could be disastrous ( not really but it could happen. )

Comment: The Foreach-Object is unnecessary. You can pipe directly into Rename-Item e.g. `... | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '1',$int++}`

Comment: @KeithHill It would do named parameter assignment... edit forthcoming. Thanks. The curly braces should be fine here as well?

Comment: You have to use curly braces in this scenario to gain access to the pipeline object using $_.  This trick, using curly braces to evaluate a parameter's argument, works only for pipeline bound parameters.

Comment: @KeithHill thanks for getting back. Was removing the quotes and aesthetic choice or did it serve a purpose.

Comment: Unnecessary.  You don't need to quote string arguments to commands unless the string contains spaces.  That is the benefit of PowerShell being a shell.  You never see folks quote an arg like that in other shells e.g. `cmd /c dir 1.jpg /s`